# Why does this starred message not show up on the list of all starred messages?

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

On the [room info of Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=stars), this is the last page of the overview of all starred messages:

[image]

Here is the latest starred message (from that list) on the transcript:

[image]

But if you look even further back in the transcript:

[image]

... then you see a message with 3 stars that's even older. Why isn't it showing up on the latest page of the 'all' tab on the room info?

Comment: Appears to be a bug, though very minor. It doesn't really matter that it doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so I should not ask this question?

Comment: No no, that's not what I meant. Just that because it's very minor, the chances of it being fixed are very low.